# Duplicating messages in Firebase one to one Chat Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been having some trouble implementing data into firebase but it gets duplicated and out of order there is something wrong with adding messages to the database when clicking on fab.setOnClickListener.

And i think its something to do with my ordering(i use messageCount for ordering) when adding the messages to Firebase. Well here is the code and picture of the firebase Database.

Code:

```
private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
private ListView listView;
private int messagesCount = 0;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

private User mUser;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //find views by Ids
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    try {
        mUser = getUserFromBundle();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // User is already signed in, show list of messages
        getMessagesCount();
        showAllOldMessages();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: USER SELECT TO CHAT WITH********************** " + mUser.getUser_id());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //messagesCount = 0;
            getMessagesCount();
            if (input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter some texts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages -- BEFORE 2 *******************************" + messagesCount);
                //messagesCount = 0;

                 myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child(String.valueOf(messagesCount + 1))
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        );
                //getMessagesCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages AFTER 1 --- *******************************" + messagesCount);

                myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                        .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child(String.valueOf(messagesCount))
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        );
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages AFTER 2 --- *******************************" + messagesCount);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showAllOldMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in failed, please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void showAllOldMessages() {
    loggedInUserName = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Log.d("Main", "user id: " + loggedInUserName);

    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.item_in_message,
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child(mUser.getUser_id()));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private User getUserFromBundle(){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        return bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_user));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

private void getMessagesCount(){
    //messagesCount = 0;
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(mUser.getUser_id());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found post:" + singleSnapshot.getValue());
                messagesCount++;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages *******************************" + messagesCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Picture of database : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc3e9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Database keys are strings. Even when you put numeric values in them (which Firebase recommends quite strongly against), they are stored as string values. This means that the keys are sorted lexicographically: by string value. And in that sort order `"11"` comes before `"8"`.

To fix this you have a few options:

- Make sure the numbers are all of the same length. In that scenario `00008` comes before `00011`.
- Use [Firebase Push IDs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) as the keys of the messages. While these are less easy to visually parse than the numbers you use now, they solve this (and *many* other) problems.

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen.